# Здравствуйте. Помогите новичку в написании кода. Мне нужно в одномерном массиве вычислить сумму значений массива с нечетными индексами

Tags: python

```
#Произвадим ввод библиотек математики и рандома
from math import*
from random import*
#Здесь производим вывод надписи на экран и попутно элемент для вычисления
n=int(input("Введите количество элементов в массиве: " ))
#Вводим пустой массив
arr=[]
#Производим ввод массива (я взял массив от -15 до 15)
for i in range(n):
    arr.append(randint(-15,15))
    #Производим показ получившегося массива
print(arr)
min=arr[0]
#Зададим в 2 единицы для вычисления
#Одну из них берем за 0
k=0
j=1
#Пишем условие для j
x=j%2==0
#В последней строке не уверен что она правильная
```

Comment: Ну послушайте. Если каждому новичку помогать, то глядишь какой-нибудь переплюнет старого служаку. И старичок окажется не удел. 
Не надо помогать всякому просящему! Сарказм, ирония и правда жизти:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создадим функцию которая принимает на вход массив и выводит сумму нечётных индексов

```
def odd_sum(a) -> int:
    s = 0
    for i in range(1, len(a), 2):
        s += a[i]
    return s
```

Comment: Благодарю. Надеюсь поможет

Comment: Если вам помогло решение, отметьте его, пожалуйста, как ответ :3

Comment: Soup, извините, но я не понял куда именно вставлять ваш код и написал по итогу свой, но все таки отмечу :3

Comment: @Dblnya Ваш код неверен, он считает не то. А "куда вставить" - вызвать эту функцию `summ = odd_sum(arr)`

Comment: Я пишу `-> int`, чтобы задать строгую типизацию для **выходного** значения. Входное значение так же остаётся типа `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Пишем сумму значений массива в нечетных индексах:

```
Sum=0
for j in range(n):
    if arr[j]%2==1:
        Sum+=arr[j]
print(Sum)
```